# run static method from a thread pool in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, static-methods

What is the best way to run a static method in several threads, using a thread pool?
Also I trying to pass an argument to the static method. something like

```
Class A{
 public static runTask(int i){
   ....
 }

}
```

and from a main:

```
ThreadPool pool = new ThreadPool(5, "poolname");

for(int i=1; i<10; i++){

   A.runTask(i) // but on a new thread...

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you are not intending to use mutable static fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for **[java.util.concurrent.Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)**.  It should meet your needs.  Here is a simple example of using it:

```
public class ExecutorServiceTest {
    static ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Queue 10 executions of someTask into the threadPool 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            runSomeTaskInThreadPool();
        }
        // the shutdown method causes the executor to:
        // 1. stop accepting new tasks, and
        // 2. allow previously queued jobs to complete, and
        // 3. shut down all pooled threads once all jobs are complete  
        threadPool.shutdown();
        // block until the threadPool has finished shutting down,
        // which indicates that all tasks have finished executing
        threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private static void runSomeTaskInThreadPool() {
        Future future = threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                someTask();
            }
        });
        // TODO: Maybe keep track of futures to monitor success/failure of task
    }

    static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    public static void someTask() {
        System.out.println("someTask: " + counter.incrementAndGet() 
                + " on thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? which one of the executors, and how exactly it should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the detailed implementation guides:
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/threads/chap13.pdf